# VBA INSERT INTO with ADO parameters

Tags: vba, ms-access, foreach, insert, ado

I'm working in ACCESS VBA. I have a sub, which inserting the given collection into different tables, which depends on the current element. I just met and would like to work with this ADO parameter thing, because I have problem with the simple `docmd.runsql "insert into..."`. The problem is that some strings contain "`'`" character, so I got error at these records. I searched and found ADO parameters, but no good tutorials and now I'm tired from the error codes which are not helpful either (coming from java).
My code snippet:

```
Dim adoCMD As Object
Set adoCMD = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With adoCMD
    .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pKey", adInteger)
    .parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pTitle", adVarChar, 100)
    .parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pid", adInteger)
    .parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pAired", adDate)
    .parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pmtype", adInteger)
    .parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pSyear", adSmallInt)
    .parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pSeason", adInteger)
    If addDate Then
        .parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pAdded", adDate)
    End If
    For Each elem In ac
        If elem.aired >= seasonStart And elem.aired <= seasonEnd Then
            key = Nz(DMax("table_Akey", "table_A"), 0) + 1
            .parameters("pKey").Value = key
            .parameters("pTitle").Value = elem.title
            .parameters("pid").Value = elem.id
            .parameters("pAired").Value = elem.aired
            .parameters("pmtype").Value = elem.mtype
            .parameters("pSyear").Value = syear
            .parameters("pSeason").Value = season
            If addDate Then
                .parameters("pAdded").Value = Date
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO table_A(table_Akey,title,id,aired,media,seasonyear,season,added) VALUES(pKey,pTitle,pid,pAired,pmtype,pSyear,pSeason,pAdded);"
            Else
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO table_A(table_Akey,title,id,aired,media,seasonyear,season) VALUES(pKey,pTitle,pid,pAired,pmtype,pSyear,pSeason);"
            End If
        Else
            wCounter = wCounter + 1
            key = Nz(DMax("wskey", "ws"), 0) + 1
            .parameters("pKey").Value = key
            .parameters("pTitle").Value = elem.title
            .parameters("pid").Value = elem.id
            .parameters("pAired").Value = elem.aired
            .parameters("pmtype").Value = elem.mtype
            .parameters("pSyear").Value = syear
            .parameters("pSeason").Value = season
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO ws(wskey,title,id,aired,media,wsyear,season) VALUES(pKey,pTitle,pid,pAired,pmtype,pSyear,pSeason);"
        End If
        .Execute
    Next elem
End With
```

I get the error: Runtime Error '3001' Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range or are in conflict with one another
at the line

```
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pTitle", adVarChar, 100)
```

Maybe the whole code is wrong, I don't know how to do properly with ADO parameters, but you can see what I want to do. I give a collection to the function. I loop through the elements and place them the right table and I have one switch as well (`addDae`).

Please help me.

Comment: Generally, if you're using an ODBC provider, the parameters in the SQL statement are given with `?` as a placeholder instead of the parameter name: `VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`. I'm also pretty sure that you can't use an "optional" parameter like `pAdded` that way - the number of parameters has to match the `CommandText`.

Comment: @Comintern The number of parameters will match every time. Anyways, tried without it, still getting the same error at the same line. About the `VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)` thing: how should I assign the values in the loop? `.parameters("?").value=`. Generally is not working at this time. You just wrote a comment without taking a good look at my code and thinking. Nothing helpful. :( Sorry if I'm harsh, but I tried a lot of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also write a function that escapes the DB single quote. Generally, a single quote is "escaped" by doubling it. It would be something like:

```
Function escapeDBquote(s As String) As String
    Dim sOut As String
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    While (i <= len(s))
        If (Mid(s, i, 1) = "'") Then sOut = sOut +"'"
        sOut = sOut + Mid(s, i, 1)
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    escapeDBquote = sOut
End Function
```

and call it like:

```
Dim szSQL As String
szSQL = "insert into myTable (sfield1, ..) values ('" + escapeDBquote(myString) + "');"
```

(Note: haven't compiled this code; there could be some typos.)

Comment: Working like a charm! Thank you! I have some similar problem at my work as well (I want to insert some `double` with decimal comma  `,` like 3,14159) but I get error with no matching argument numbers. I'm curious, do you have some idea for it? :D And it's really pain in the ass concatenating a long `INSERT INTO`, so I'd like to see how to solve my original post with ADO parameters as well. Anyway, I give you a nice green thing. ^^

Comment: Junpet, most programming languages and DB systems are English-language oriented and don't use the comma as decimal separator. Use the decimal point. Note that e.g. Excel can show numbers with the comma as decimal separator, but that is just _presentation_. Internally, it is just stored as floating point numbers.

Comment: I live in such a country, where we use decimal comma, not a point. When I do some calculation in VBA, store it as `double` and if I call that variable, it says 3,14159. What can I do? My VBA working with decimal comma but my ACCESS DB working with decimal point with `INSERT INTO` command (and I can see decimal comma in the resultset). Really frustrating. To clear out: I'd like to insert `double` variables, like `"INSERT INTO table_A(xy) VALUES(" & doubleVariable & ");" So, it's not just presentation, when my code fail at this time IMO.

Comment: Your problem smells like a client using decimal comma and a server using decimal point. To debug your problem, first set on the client _Control Panel ---> Region and Language --> Formats --> Additional Settings --> Decimal symbol_ to use the decimal point as separator. Internally Excel, Access and DBs use IEEE floating point values.