# Clean Sql Query ran in VBA

Tags: sql, vba

I'm running an Insert Into SQL query from VBA, and I recently came across the string 'Women's Health / Sexual Health', which contains the ' character, and thus the query failed because ' is a text delimiter. This is how I get the text for the query:

```
Function getSqlInsertIntoQuery(arrHeaders, arrValues, tableIndex As enumTables)
    Dim dHeadersAndValues As New scripting.Dictionary
    Dim TableName As String

    TableName = getTableName(tableIndex)

    getSqlInsertIntoQuery = "INSERT INTO " & TableName & " ( [" & _
         Join(arrHeaders, "]," & vbNewLine & "[") & "])" & _
        " VALUES( " & Chr(39) & Join(arrValues, Chr(39) & "," & Chr(39)) & Chr(39) & ") ;"

    Debug.Print getSqlInsertIntoQuery
End Function
```

Can anyone tell me of a way to clean the text of special characters that I should escape? Or is there a list of characters that I can replace using regex?

Comment: Are you using ADO? Use `ADODB.Parameter` - no more hassles with formatting any data.

Comment: @FunThomas thanks for the idea, can you directly to an example or use case of how to use it? Google gives me unrelated answers because "Parameter" is widely used.

Comment: Here's an example of using parameters - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437480/vba-insert-into-with-ado-parameters.  You'd need to do a little more work to build the SQL though, since you have a variable list of fields/values.

Comment: They both answered your question; another reason to parametrize is the serious issue of SQL injection: here an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50166053/2752308) that explains and avoid it, even for DAO